# pass variables into command button

Tags: commandbutton

I have a command button which has an action status and param values .please see code below

```
<apex:commandButton id="songdbabc" action="{!synchsongmethod}" 
    immediate="true" status="counterStatus" 
    value="Synch from song db" 
    oncomplete="simplejavascriptfunction();return false;" 
    rerender="songblock" 
    rendered="{!IF(checkUserAdmin && 
        ((case.Status=='New') || (case.Status=='In Progress') || 
        (case.Status=='Resubmit for Verification')) && 
        (case.Last_RapidCue_Submission__c!=null),True,False)}">
    <apex:param name="seqId" value="{!wrapSong.seqObject.id}" 
        assignTo="{!sid}"/>
</apex:commandbutton>
```

Now oncomplete i want to call a javascript function and pass values as

```
oncomplete="testsort('segSec{!segment.Segment_Order_No__c}');return false;"`
```

However i am getting error:

> unknown controller property segment

Segment is an apex variable as below:

```
<apex:variable var="segment" value="{!segList[0]}"/>
```

But in command button segment is being recognized as controller property. I know that using input button I can get pass that error message but we cant use input button as it we cant use status in input button

Is there any other way of going around this , Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: Similar to a variable in apex, `apex:variable` also has a scope and is only accessible inside declared tag. You might want to move the variable to top/higher location so that it'd be accessible to the oncomplete method. Other than that, its really hard to understand what you want to achieve. Also avoid using `return false;` instead use rerender tag to stop complete page reload.

Comment: I tried placing the button in the same scope as apex :variable but i still get the same message

Comment: Would like to see the complete code, that would help to troubleshoot.